# Empty Grub after installing windows over kali

Tags: kali-linux, grub

I used Windows and Kali Linux together for some time. Yesterday I changed my Windows, but after reinstalling Windows, grub was gone and the laptop was directly booting to Windows.

(Both Kali and Windows are in EFI and HDD is GPT)

I made changes to the BIOS but that didn't work, so I installed grub in the **Windows EFI partition** using live kali. After that, the grub was loading but it is empty and it's just minimal grub-bash.

I can access the previous grub menu (before the Windows reinstall) when I use the commands:

```
set prefix=(kali_grub_partition)/grub
set root=(kali_root_partition)
insmod normal
normal
```

Is there anyway to fix this without reinstalling OS?

NOTE: when I installed Kali at first i separated boot partition and root partition

UPDATE:
[EFI Partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q7Fj.png)

Comment: This is not a security question. You just installed an OS over the previous ones and now they're gone. Just be more careful next time.

Comment: There's no "Windows EFI partition", there one EFI partition. That's the first thing you need to know and understand. Only one per system is required regardless of how many drives and how many OS are installed and in any combination.  But you can have ONE per drive (backup/fallback) but at any given time UEFI is reading from one and that one only. Assuming that you reinstalled Windows correctly, all you would need to do was UEFI > Boot and change it back to "Kali", boot and run `sudo update-grub`. It's really this simple.

Comment: windows is working correctly, also when i boot into kali it is working, the EFI partition EFI and grub folder, th EFI folder contains 3 folders, EFI, kali, Microsoft

Comment: Great! Boot Kali and run a command above. Then you should be able to boot both from the Grub menu.

Comment: i'm in kali but running that command doesn't fix problem

Comment: check EFI Partition picture

Comment: So, how exactly are you booting Kali and Windows?

Comment: grub-minimal is working but it has no entry, in that i run those commands that i mentioned in question, then somehow it shows kali and windwos

Comment: You need to reinstall Grub. Make sure (1) you're actually booting Kali in UEFI mode and (2) the target drive is the one containing the EFI partition.

Comment: You may want to use Ubuntu's Boot Repair (works for Debian and anyDebian based distro)